# Selenium hides web element behind navigation bar

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have a problem with writing a value into an input element.
[image: a busy cat]
When Selenium appeals to this input field, the page scrolls to the top and the input hides behind the navigation bar.

Before appealing, I execute this code:

```
int elementPosition = element.getLocation().getY();
String js = String.format("window.scroll(0, %s)", elementPosition-90);
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(js);
```

But even after my scroll, the input is still hidden.

Also, I tried to set a value to this field through JavaScript:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '"+date+"')",element);
```

Unfortunately, this does not help either.

Environment: Selenium 3.6.0 ver, FireFox 66 ver.

Comment: Are you saying that after you click into the input field the screen scrolls? How does this work if you're not using automation?

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Instead of asking for help with your solution to the problem, edit your question and ask about the actual problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DebanjanB This isn't an X-Y problem. He's explained what the actual problem is (with pictures) and what he's done to solve it.

Comment: I'm wondering if your locator is locating the wrong element? Maybe that's why it seems to be scrolling down so far? Can you share the URL of the page?

Comment: @JeffC url - https://aphlweb.labwebportal.com/ca/#/login
locator for input field - `//div[contains(@data-item-id, 'dateCollected')]//design-item-date-picker//input`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code resolved my problem

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(false); arguments[0].focus();", element);
actions.sendKeys(date).perform();
```